# just installed ubuntu 13.04 is running extremely slow

Tags: 13.04

i'm new in the linux os, i just installed ubuntu 13.04 32 bits but it´s running very slow, whatever i do it takes a lot. I have a:

- Motherboard: Via pc3500g
- memory: 1gb ddr2
- Graphics: integrated VIA Chrome9 HC Graphics core with Chromotion CE
- 1.8Ghz VIA C7-D processor

Im new using this os any help would be very helpful.

Comment: older hardware often has trouble running the latest Ubuntu versions, so you may be better off installing either an earlier Ubuntu release (like 12.04LTS in this case) or switch to a lighter, less resource-intensive Ubuntu variant like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Via is not  well Supported for Ubuntu. Check out this Post:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenChrome

Answer (score 0):

1Gb of memory is not enough for modern mainstream distros. And your video card is exotic, which is a linux bugger number one. 
Unity can no more work in 2D mode properly. I guess you should try to switch to Xubuntu. You can do it without reinstallation. Lots of guides on the net. In XFCE, do turn off 3D composition, if any will be. 
If this doesn't help, you better change Ubuntu to something more straightforward. You may try Gentoo if you have some time. It is not as scary as people say. Just follow installation guide line-by-line, and use `genkernel all` and proper profile. KDE can still work great in unaccelerated video mode. And Gentoo nedds much less RAM.